# How to sign in automatically if login user Information exist in sharedpreferences in android

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have Three activity which will load based on different type user. I stored logged-in user info in sharedpreferences  when log-in. I remove user info after clicking logout button. Now I need to check if record exist in sharedpreferences until log-Out user can automatically sign in to app. How to do it. Here is my code:

```
   try {
            object = new JSONObject(root.getTextContent().toString());
            StatusValue  = object.getString("status");
            UserInfoValue  = object.getString("UserInfo");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("UserInfoValues", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("UserInfos", UserInfoValue);
        editor.commit();
        // Log.d("Value:" ,Value);
        txtView.setText(StatusValue);
        if(StatusValue.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
        {
            String userType = null;
            //SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserInfoValues", MODE_PRIVATE);
            // String restoredText = prefs.getString("UserInfos", null);
            try {
                JSONObject infoObject = new JSONObject(UserInfoValue);
                userType = infoObject.getString("UserType");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("NormalUser"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,NewBookingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Loged In As Normal User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("HelpDesk"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,DriverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Loged In As HelpDesk User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Car"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,DriverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Loged In As Car User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your launcher Activity,

```
boolean isRegistered = preferences.getBoolean("isRegistered", false);

if(isRegistered){
 //continue to your home screen
}else {
//show login page
}
```

and after user logs in, update your sharedpreference like this,

```
editor.putBoolean("isRegistered", true).commit();
```

and when user logs out, update your sharedpreference like this,

```
editor.putBoolean("isRegistered", false).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference when user login validated and go for next activity like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username);
    editor.putString("password", password);
    editor.putString("type","admin");
    editor.apply();
```

then where you use your splash put this:

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    username = sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
    password = sharedPreferences.getString("password","");
    type = sharedPreferences.getString("type","");
    if(!(username.equals("") && password.equals(""))){
        if(type.equals("admin")){
           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AfterAdLog.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(type.equals("member")){
            Intent i1 = new Intent(getActivity(), AfterLogMem.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Admin and member login so i've used "type" there u can delete that field.